# sending email by using json

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am trying to send email and the code working fine 
this part should be the reply after clicking on submit but when i click submit it 
this is what appears

```
{"nameMessage":"","emailMessage":"","messageMessage":""}
```

this is the part that is not working properly

```
var postdata = $('.contact-form form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sendmail.php',
        data: postdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if(json.nameMessage != '') {
                $('.contact-form form .nameLabel').append(' - <span class="violet" style="font-size: 13px; font-style: italic"> ' + json.nameMessage + '</span>');
            }
            if(json.emailMessage != '') {
                $('.contact-form form .emailLabel').append(' - <span class="violet" style="font-size: 13px; font-style: italic"> ' + json.emailMessage + '</span>');
            }
            if(json.messageMessage != '') {
                $('.contact-form form .messageLabel').append(' - <span class="violet" style="font-size: 13px; font-style: italic"> ' + json.messageMessage + '</span>');
            }
            if(json.nameMessage == '' && json.emailMessage == '' && json.messageMessage == '') {
                $('.contact-form form').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $('.contact-form').append('<p><span class="violet">Thanks for contacting us!</span> We will get back to you very soon.</p>');
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is the JSON response from your PHP not what you want? If that's the case, we need to see some PHP.

Comment: Unrelated, but your CSS class names should describe the content not the styling - having class `violet` is no better than hard-coding the colour into the style attribute.

Comment: Do you have `header("Content-Type : application/json");` in your `.php` file. I am guessing that `string` is returned instead of `json` object.

Comment: Read and understand the code in sendmail.php and you will find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not very clear, What your code does is send a mail for contacting and your php sends error messages for name, email or message (if inappropriate)

So you are saying that you are receiving

```
{"nameMessage":"","emailMessage":"","messageMessage":""}
```

as response for your ajax request, which should work perfectly, either your response from PHP is something else, you should check your network request and see whats coming as response, also check the data that is being sent.